# Signal handling per process on Windows

Tags: c++, c++11, posix

In my C++ app I need to catch signal `SIGSEGV`, so on Linux it's easy, but on Windows I have a problem: signal from another thread didn't catch by handler.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void setPosixSignalHandler() {
    signal(SIGSEGV, [&](int sig) {
        std::cout << "Received SIGSEGV" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    });
}

void f() {
    raise(SIGSEGV);
}

int main() {
    setPosixSignalHandler();

    std::thread t(f);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

If I remove multithreading than it's working like a charm.
Is it possible to set a single handler for all threads?

I'm using MinGW64.

Comment: Do you mean signal handling per process or per thread?

Comment: In posted code i have a signal handler per thread, but i need a single handler for all threads

Comment: AFAIK, MS-Windows doesn't have POSIX signals, so whatever that does is probably an emulation. In any case, I'd also question whether catching segmentation violations is useful, because they typically occur as a sign of internal memory corruption or inconsistency, which is hard to recover from if your code depends on that internal sanity.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, we are developing application that uses huge 3d-party open source software, and we can't 100% sure that it works properly on different platforms with various input data. Yeah, I can use debugger and it will be a correct solution, but i want to print backtrace in log file (like crash dump) if any error occured (particular, segfault), so we can quickly locate a problem occured at client side.